# Count the number of valid observations (no NA) pairwise in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

Say I have a data frame like this:

```
Df <- data.frame(
    V1 = c(1,2,3,NA,5),
    V2 = c(1,2,NA,4,5),
    V3 = c(NA,2,NA,4,NA)
)
```

Now I want to count the number of valid observations for every combination of two variables. For that, I wrote a function `sharedcount`:

```
sharedcount <- function(x,...){
    nx <- names(x)
    alln <- combn(nx,2)
    out <- apply(alln,2,
      function(y)sum(complete.cases(x[y]))
    )
    data.frame(t(alln),out)
}
```

This gives the output:

```
> sharedcount(Df)
  X1 X2 out
1 V1 V2   3
2 V1 V3   1
3 V2 V3   2
```

All fine, but the function itself takes pretty long on big dataframes (600 variables and about 10000 observations). I have the feeling I'm overseeing an easier approach, especially since cor(...,use='pairwise') is running still a whole lot faster while it has to do something similar :

```
> require(rbenchmark)    
> benchmark(sharedcount(TestDf),cor(TestDf,use='pairwise'),
+     columns=c('test','elapsed','relative'),
+     replications=1
+ )
                           test elapsed relative
2 cor(TestDf, use = "pairwise")    0.25     1.0
1           sharedcount(TestDf)    1.90     7.6
```

Any tips are appreciated.

---

**Note** : Using Vincent's trick, I wrote a function that returns the same data frame. Code in my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following is slightly faster:

```
x <- !is.na(Df)
t(x) %*% x

#       test elapsed relative
#    cor(Df)  12.345 1.000000
# t(x) %*% x  20.736 1.679708
```

Comment: Very nice! `crossprod(x)` instead of `t(x) %*% x` can improve a little still. I still need to get that into a data frame like in the example, but that's not that difficult.

Comment: As your trick was the one that cut the time, you're the accepted answer. I gave my own function as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 3):

I thought Vincent's looked really elegant, not to mention being faster than my sophomoric for-loop, except it seems to be needing an extraction step which I added below. This is just an example of the heavy overhead in the apply method when used with dataframes.

```
shrcnt <- function(Df) {Comb <- t(combn(1:ncol(Df),2) )
shrd <- 1:nrow(Comb)
for (i in seq_len(shrd)){ 
     shrd[i] <- sum(complete.cases(Df[,Comb[i,1]], Df[,Comb[i,2]]))}
return(shrd)}

   benchmark(
      shrcnt(Df), sharedcount(Df), {prs <- t(x) %*% x; prs[lower.tri(prs)]}, 
      cor(Df,use='pairwise'),
        columns=c('test','elapsed','relative'),
        replications=100
      )
 #--------------
                       test elapsed relative
3                         {   0.008      1.0
4 cor(Df, use = "pairwise")   0.020      2.5
2           sharedcount(Df)   0.092     11.5
1                shrcnt(Df)   0.036      4.5
```

Comment: Also a nice optimization. Take home lesson for me : use indices, not names.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the lovely trick of Vincent and the additional `lower.tri()` suggestion of DWin, I came up with following function that gives me the same output (i.e. a data frame) as my original one, and runs a whole lot faster :

```
sharedcount2 <- function(x,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,...){
    counts <- crossprod(!is.na(x))
    id <- lower.tri(counts)
    count <- counts[id]
    X1 <- colnames(counts)[col(counts)[id]]
    X2 <- rownames(counts)[row(counts)[id]]
    data.frame(X1,X2,count)
}
```

Note the use of `crossprod()`, as that one gives a small improvement compared to `%*%`, but it does exactly the same.

The timings :

```
> benchmark(sharedcount(TestDf),sharedcount2(TestDf),
+           replications=5,
+           columns=c('test','replications','elapsed','relative'))

                  test replications elapsed relative
1  sharedcount(TestDf)            5   10.00 90.90909
2 sharedcount2(TestDf)            5    0.11  1.00000
```

**Note:** I supplied TestDf in the question, as I noticed that the timings differ depending on the size of the data frames. As shown here, the time increase is a lot more dramatic than when compared using a small data frame.